# How to have SonarQube query and display jira details

Tags: jenkins, jira, sonarqube

I have a requirement where in i want to display the JIRA issues in my SonarQube.  I configured the details in SonarQube.  Unfortunately the data is not updated frequently.  The data gets updated only when something gets pushed to sonar from a jenkins job.  Is there a way to manually trigger an event or poll JIRA from SonarQube to get the live data?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

And actually, we don't plan to make extra efforts on this plugin for the following reason: we consider that SonarQube is not a multi-purpose dashboard application but instead a plaform centered on source code. So everything not closely related to source code has nothing to do in SonarQube.